# ArrayFire convolution issue with Cuda backend

Tags: c++, opencl, arrayfire

I've been having an issue with a certain function call in the

```
dphaseWeighted = af::convolve(dphaseWeighted, m_slowTimeFilter);
```

which seem to produce nothing but nan's.

The back ground is we have recently switched from using AF OpenCL to AF Cuda and the problem that we are seeing happens in the function.

```
dphaseWeighted = af::convolve(dphaseWeighted, m_slowTimeFilter);
```

This seems to work well when using OpenCL.

Unfortunatley, I can't give you the whole function because of IP. only a couple of snippets.

This convolve lies deep with in a phase extract piece of code. and is actualy the second part of that code which uses the af::convolve funtion.
The first function seems to behave as expected, with sensible floating point data out.
but then when it comes to the second function all I'm seeing is nan's coming out ( I view that with af_print amd dumping the data to a file.

in the CMakeList I include

```
include_directories(${ArrayFire_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

and

```
target_link_libraries(DASPhaseInternalLib ${ArrayFire_CUDA_LIBRARIES})
```

and it builds as expected.

Has anyone experience any think like this before?